# How can run akka 2.1-snapshots with scala 2.9.x?

Tags: akka

When upgrade akka from 1.2 to akka 2.0.2, I cannot implement camel because akka 2.0.2 have not support akka-camel, I tried to use akka 2.1-snapshots but it required scala 2.10, how can i run akka 2.1-snapshots with scala 2.9.x?

When i compile testkit always have this error:

> class file needed by TestKitBase is missing. [error] reference value
>   util of package concurrent refers to nonexisting symbol. [error] one
>   error found

If i copy scala-reflect-2.10.0-M5.jar , scala-library-2.10-M5.jar, scalatest-2.10-M5.jar to my library folder, have other error:

> error while loading package, class file needed by package is missing.
>   [error] reference value $default$2 of object deprecated refers
>   to nonexisting symbol.

I'm using sbt 0.11.3 & here is my build.sbt file:

name := "akka-2.1-test"

> version := "1.0.0"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.9.1"
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots"
>
> unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "custom_lib" }

I don't want to upgrade to scala 2.10 because my liftweb still use scala 2.9.1

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that Akka 2.1 will be released for Scala 2.9.x, because it uses lot of new features from Scala 2.10.